# How to determine time complexity of EM algorithm of probabilistic PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, latent-variable, time-complexity

I was studying probabilistic PCA from Bishop's book. There an EM algorithm is provided to calculate principal subspace:

[image]

[image]

Here $\mathbf M$ is $M\times M$ matrix, $\mathbf W$ is $D\times M$ matrix and $(\mathbf x_n − \mathbf x)$ is vector $D\times 1$.
Later in the book there is statement regarding the time complexity:

> Instead, the most computationally demanding steps are those involving sums over
>   the data set that are $\mathcal O(NDM)$.

I was wondering if anyone can help me understanding the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you interested in how to derive the $O(NDM)$ estimate?

Comment: @AlexR. yes, I am.